# Displaying google search without using Google API?

Tags: python, google-search

I want to make Google browser which when supplied with key word returns search results and download any file as required. I have created the downloader need help on searching part how to about it? I want to do it in python as I have created the downloader in the same.

Comment: What doe s `download any file as required.' mean?

Comment: files which come up like when we search a book's name and some times its pdf comes up so to download it. no worries i have done that .

Comment: So, you want to send queries to google and then scrape the results for links that you can use without going through their API?

Comment: Why not use the API? I think you need to. See section 5.3 of the Terms of Service: http://www.google.com/accounts/TOS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Section 5.3 of the Terms of Service (http://www.google.com/accounts/TOS), you need to use the API.

Here's their custom search API, which can be used to search the whole web: http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html

Comment: main problem is it restrict number of searches thats bad

Comment: You're restricted to zero searches if you don't use it. Also, you can get additional quota by paying a small amount ($5 / 1000 queries).